# Nav item links not properly linking to new page

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am using Django to do this,

I have a nav list with tabs and I want each tab to go to a new page and new corresponding view, the new pages will all have the same nav list, just with a different active tab.

For some reason when I click on the tab, it won't change the page, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code in the main page with the tabs:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#summary">Summary</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link external" data-toggle="tab" href="{% url 'financials:description' ticker %}">Description</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I know the link is correct, because I have tested it outside the nav links and it works fine. When I hover over the tab I see the proper URL at the bottom of page, but when I click nothing happens. I'm not sure if this has to do with javascript (I don't understand javascript yet and got the website template online). Here is some javascript that may be causing a problem:

```
, $(".one-page-scroll .nav-item a").on("click", function (o) {
        var t = $(this);
        $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
        $(t).parent().addClass('active');
        $('body').removeClass('openmenu');
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(t.attr("href")).offset().top - 50
        }, 1500, "easeInOutExpo"), o.preventDefault()
    }), $(document).on("click", ".navbar-collapse.show", function (o) {
        $(o.target).is("a") && $(this).collapse("hide")
    }), $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ? $(".back_top").fadeIn() : $(".back_top").fadeOut()
    }), $(".back_top").on("click", function () {
        return $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1e3), !1
```

Thanks, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to tell from here. Can we take a look at your urls.py and views.py files?

Comment: I will try to add them if theres room, but I don't believe the problem is with them, as I have tried the same <a href tag outside the li tag and it works as expected. Clicking the tab is not giving an error, it's just not doing anything at all. 

When I have the tabs and don't try sending it to another page, they work fine as well.

Comment: Try keeping the console open as you click on the link. It might give you some useful error message

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by taking out the: data-toggle="tab". Not entirely sure what that does but hopefully it doesnt break anything else!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="summary">Summary</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link external" data-toggle="tab" href="{url 'financials:description' ticker }">Description</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```